# Change table column order while preserving the foreign key constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, ssms

I have a table in a SQL server 2012 database table with the following columns

```
Id (PK)
Name 
UserId (FK)
Created
Updated
```

I want to change the order of the columns by swapping the Name and UserId to

```
Id (PK)
UserId (FK)
Name
Created
Updated
```

Please note that the table do not contain any data at the moment. Usually I do not bother with writing ALTER scripts and simply use SQL Management Studio to create and modify my tables. I would usually simply use the DROP AND CREATE TO menu option to re create the table and modify the order of the columns, but in this case the foreign key constraint is preventing me from doing this successfully.

Is there any way that I can change the order of the database columns while preserving the foreign key constraint? The only other solution I can see is to remove the foreign key constraint, re create the table and add the foreign key constraint again.

Comment: No, there's no "magic" way to do this. If you use the visual designer in SSMS, it will basically re-create the table with the new column order, copy the data over, and drop the old table. But ***why*** is the column order so important to you? In the relational model, you should **not** rely on any particular order - the order should be without significance, really

Comment: I agree, the order is of no significant importance, the database is still in the design phase and this is simply a matter of OCD :) If this was an existing database already deployed in a production environment I would have added the column to the end of the table. Was just curious if there is 'magic' way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The on-disk order is different (and has a fixed method of doing it) to the apparent column order in the CREATE. It makes no difference.

That is, [sys.columns.column_id](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176106.aspx) order does not match on-disk order

- [Performance / Space implications when ordering SQL Server columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6692021/performance-space-implications-when-ordering-sql-server-columns/6692107#6692107)
- [How do you get to limits of 8060 bytes per row and 8000 per (varchar, nvarchar) value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793022/how-to-come-to-limits-of-8060-bytes-per-row-and-8000-per-varchar-nvarchar-val/3793265#3793265)